# Two string columns with stored datapoints - access one by the other

Tags: r, string, matrix, strsplit

i have a dataframe with basically two columns and "dates" in one and "grade of disease" in the other.

They are coded as follows:

| Date | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-10-14=&=2018-01-20=&==&= | 1=&=2=&==&= |
| 2018-10-14=&=2019-01-20=&=2020-01-01=&= | 2=&=3=&=4=&= |

I look for a code to access the date from the first column that corresponds to the Grade in the second columns.
Additionally it would be a great help to be able to extract the date, when Grade of disease was e.g. 2 for the first time.

I tried str_split(... sep = "=&=) and end up with a matrix with all different dates and grades.

I would need to extract the following:

1. For time-varying analysis

| Follow_up_1 | Grade_1 | Follow_up_2 | Grade_2 | Follow_up_3 | Grade_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-10-14 | 1 | 2018-01-20 | 2 | NA | NA |
| 2018-10-14 | 2 | 2019-01-20 | 3 | 2020-01-01 | 4 |

2. Date of max_grade and max_grade

| Date_max_grade | Max_grade |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-01-20 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 | 4 |

3. Extract the first date, where the corresponding grade is 3 or 4.

| First_Date_3_or_4 |
| --- |
| NA |
| 2019-01-20 |
| 2020-01-01 |

Thanks in advance,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Date,    ~Grade,
  "2017-10-14=&=2018-01-20=&==&=",  "1=&=2=&==&=",
    "2018-10-14=&=2019-01-20=&=2020-01-01=&=",  "2=&=3=&=4=&="
)
```

setup:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~str_split(.x, pattern = "=&=") %>% map(~.x[.x != ""]))
  ) %>%
  pmap(~data.frame(...)) %>%
  imap_dfr(~mutate(.x, group = .y, group_id = row_number())) %>%
  mutate(
    Grade = as.integer(as.character(Grade)),
    Date = as.Date(Date)
  )
```

1st question:

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = group,
    names_from = group_id,
    names_glue = "{.value}_{group_id}",
    values_from = c(Date, Grade)
  ) %>%
  select(-group)
```

2nd question:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(Grade == max(Grade)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Date, Grade)
```

3rd question: I'm not sure what exactly you want here

```
df %>%
  group_by(group, Grade) %>%
  filter(Grade %in% c(3, 4)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group_id) %>%
  right_join(data.frame(group = unique(df$group)), by = "group")
```

Comment: Thank you! As soon as i work on the part of the code again, i will update the post.